# Expected identifier before <(> token

Tags: c

What's wrong with this code?

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef int type1[10];

typedef type1 *type2;

typedef struct {
    int field1;
   type2 field2;
} type3;

typedef type3 type4[5];

int main() {    
   type4 a;
   a[0].(*field2[3]) = 99;  // Line 16
   return 0;
}
```

Getting: **main.c:16:10: error: expected identifier before <(> token**

Gcc version: gcc (GCC) 4.7.2

Comment: Firstly, it should be `#include <stdio.h>`. Includes with double-quotes are for header files in the same directory as the source files.

Comment: Douglas B. Staple, thanks for explanation!

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Apart from the syntax error, it's full of poorly chosen names. Typedefs for pointers are usually a bad idea, for example, and the names `type1`, `type2`, `type3`, and `type4` are horrible.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple Why <stdio.h>? There's no stdio function used... :-)

Comment: @Jens yes, that's funny -- I didn't even notice that he didn't need stdio at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is really taken from a book, then it is a typo. Some correct expressions to assign an int are

```
*a[0].field2[3] = 99;
*(a[0].field2)[3] = 99;
*(a[0].field2[3]) = 99;
```

A working program would be

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int type1[10];

typedef type1 *type2;

typedef struct {
   int field1;
   type2 field2;
} type3;

typedef type3 type4[5];

int main(void) {
   type4 a;

   a[0].field1 = 99;
   a[0].field2 = malloc (sizeof(type1));
   (*a[0].field2)[3] = 99;

   return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `<stdlib.h>` because we use `malloc`.

Comment: Didn't see the answer when was writing last comment. Tried the second one. Compilation is ok. Though the program is falling at a runtime.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the example in the book.

Comment: The program crashes as long field2, which is a pointer to an array of int, is not pointing anywhere. One would need to allocate memory first.

Comment: I tested these lines 
    type1 b;
    a[0].field2 = &b;

Comment: Yup, that's another way to make the field2 pointer point to sufficient memory.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler error tells you **exactly** what's wrong:

> **expected identifier** before <(> token

You can only access structure members using their name (which is an identifier), not by some arbitrary expression.

Comment: This example was taken from "Foundations of computer science" book pages 16, 18. I thought that was right, but now I am confused.

Comment: @user2244092: Is the code in that book mean to be C, or is it in some other C-like language?

Comment: After some experiments I still have no understanding how I can access that structure. Could you explain the right way?

Comment: @user2244092 `(*a[0].field2)[3] = 99;`

Answer (score 1):

Check the [errata for the book.](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs/errata.html)

> p. 18, l. -7  The correct expression is **(*a[0].field2)[3] = 99;**
>
> Andrew Li 12/31/10

I'm not sure if it's a good or bad sign that a book first published over 20 years ago has a dozen errors (some significant!) only found in the last year.

The book may be old, but Jeff Ullman is highly respected. I remember his Compiler Design books stretching my brain decades ago...